# Tkinter RSS Feed scrolling (Left to Right)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scroll, rss

I have this bit of code in my Graduation-project-program...thing.

Extract:

[...]

```
rssfeed = tkinter.Frame(window, bg='black', width=200, height=80)
feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml')
feedShow = {'entries': [{feed['entries'][0]['title']}]}


class RSSDisplay(tkinter.Frame):[4]
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
        self.txtHeadline = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.headline = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.txtHeadline,
                                      bg='black', fg='white', font=("arial", 20))
        self.headline.grid()
        self.headlineIndex = 0
        self.updateHeadline()

    def updateHeadline(self):
        try:
            headline = feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']
        except IndexError:
            self.headlineIndex = 0
            headline = feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']
        self.txtHeadline.set(headline)
        self.headlineIndex += 1
        self.after(10000, self.updateHeadline)
```

[...]

```
RSSDisplay(window).place(x=340, y=500)
```

Now this displays the Headlines of my favorite newspaper ( La Repubblica, I'm Italian), which are updated every 10 seconds.
Since `RSSDisplay(window).place(x=340, y=500)`looks ugly beacause the text isn't centered, 'cause every sentence starts at said coordinates and not at the center for each entry in the Headlines, but always at x=340 and y=500.
I'd need it to be scrolling on top from left to right, instead of abruptly change.

If this isn't achieveable please point out to me under what conditions this could be done (i.e. changing Framework, GUI or language even thi I'd prefer to stick with Python).

If more information is needed please tell me and I'll try to add it.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: *"the text isn't centered but always starts at x=340 and y=500 I'd need it to be scrolling on top from left to right, instead of abruptly change."*: This is unclear, please [edit] your Question and explain in detail with showing related code.

Comment: Aah, i gather now what you might want: do you want something like a news ticker - where the headlines move slowly over the screen?

Comment: Well that was my desired goal, which would be awesome, but in alternative I'd like make the centred, but can't achieve that either.. I'm trying tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my take on a simple ticker: I use the `tkinter.Text` widget (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm). In `tick()` I move the `see()` function of the text widget to advance one character of the news feed to the right.
Of course, this can be much improved on (for more versatile layouting you could try to use the tkinter.Canvas widget).

```
import feedparser
import tkinter as tk

feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml')
feedShow = {'entries': [{feed['entries'][0]['title']}]}

class RSSTicker(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, height=1, wrap="none", state='disabled', **kw)
        self.headlineIndex = 0
        self.text = ''
        self.pos = 0
        self.after_idle(self.updateHeadline)
        self.after_idle(self.tick)

    def updateHeadline(self):
        try:
            self.text += '.....' + feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']
        except IndexError:
            self.headlineIndex = 0
            self.text = feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']

        self.headlineIndex += 1
        self.after(10000, self.updateHeadline)

    def tick(self):
        if self.pos < len(self.text):
        self.config(state='normal')
        self.insert('end', self.text[self.pos])
        self.pos += 1
        self.see('end')
        self.config(state='disabled')
    self.after(300, self.tick)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ticker = RSSTicker(root, bg='black', fg='white', font=("arial", 20))
    ticker.pack(side='top', fill='x')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredible. Thanks for having put that much effort in helping me, you'll be quoted in the final version of my Senior Thesis Paper. If don't understand something about your code I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter comes with different geometry managers of which I don't recommend place (not very flexible..). I am not exactly sure how you want your layout to look like. But you could try pack (besides pack there is also grid):

```
RSSDisplay(window).pack(expand='yes', fill='x')
```

I recommend to read up on how tkinter geometry managers work, e.g. here: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-geometry.htm

Note: it is not recommended (and leads to bugs) to mix different geometry managers. But it works if you use pack on the window level while using grid inside your frame - as you do to place the label with the grid method - just in case you want to add more widgets later inside your frame...

Comment: Thanks, but his results in the text being aligned at the left part of the screen and filling it's height with a white box till the other end of the screen..

Comment: Not on my screen. I have a window now containing only the frame and its label with black background. Every time it gets a new headline, the window adjusts its size.